# CRUD in a specific page in Confluence wiki

Tags: rest, wiki, confluence

I have a confluence wiki page with tables.

I would like to modify the content of the table using some remote apis/rest calls.
I can possibly update the page content using rest calls. But then every time i will be updating the content as html.I want the structure of the html exposed as api.

I know the requirement is little to much to ask for but Is it possible to do so ..any reusable components/libs for that available?

cheers,
Saurav

Comment: You could use SQL macro and fetch the data from a database, or CSV macro and fetch the data from attached file.  Both of these are much easier to update.